# Reduce PARSE_CALLS using Oracle ODP.NET (or reuse cursors)

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

When I run Queries from ODP.NET I see in V$SQL that for every call it performs a PARSE_CALL.
See:

```
select 
   s.FETCHES,s.PARSE_CALLS,s.sql_Text,s.sql_id
   from v$sql s where 
   sql_Text = 'select 1 from dual /*test2*/'
```

Returns:

[image: Results from v$SQL]

Even though I reuse the same OracleCommand and called Prepare.

Here is my .NET Code:

```
using (var c = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    c.CommandText = "select 1 from dual /*test2*/";
    c.Prepare();
    for (int i = 0; i < 9000; i++)
    {
        using (var r = c.ExecuteReader())
        {
            r.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

How can I reduce the number of Parse_Calls? 
Is there a way for me to get Oracle to keep the server side cursor for all these repeated executions, and dispose of it when I dispose the command?

I'm  using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll version 4.122.1.20170624

Comment: Stupid question: Why do you run the same statement 9000 times? Why do you use `select ... from dual` (instead of using variables directly)? Why do you use `ExecuteReader()` for a single row? Why do you not use bind variables? To make it short: please elaborate your actual problem, I assume then you will get help.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I use this to demo the problem - of course in my very real application it's a query to meaningful tables that return usually one row. That query is run multiple times due to legacy issues. I just wanted the example to be as simple as possible to reproduce on your end, so I've done it with dual

Comment: Selecting from `dual` might be different to "normal" table because `dual` is a special table in Oracle. Please provide a more realistic query.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I've tried it with a real table and got the same results. Try to repeat my experiment with any of your tables, you'll see the same results.

Comment: I am not sure but I think **every** command has to be parsed before execution. The difference is just whether it is a **soft** or a **hard** parse. Check with this query `SELECT a.name, b.value
FROM v$statname a, v$mystat b
WHERE a.statistic# = b.statistic#
AND LOWER(a.name) LIKE '%parse%';` if hard parse is increasing for each execution.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I agree that each command has to be parsed - but here I'm using the same command, and just calling executeReader. I've seen other tools Preserve the cursor in this case and reuse the same cursor. I don't know how to do that in .NET

Comment: Please share your connect string. By default, ODP.NET does "statement caching" (cursors get saved on database), but it is possible you accidentally turned it off.

Comment: Connection string: Data Source=DS;User Id=XX;Password=YY;

Initially I used connection pool:false and removing it had some affect but not at the ratio I wanted. 1000 fetches vs 943 parse_calls

Answer (score 1):

After much investigation, I saw that the solution that I want doesn't exactly exist - meaning that I can't keep the cursors open and control when they are cleared.

I can improve performance by asking .NET to keep the last X queries's cursors open  - causing a significant reduction in the "PARSE_CALLS" info.

I do that by activating Oracles connection statement cache.

Added the following to my connection string:
Statement Cache Size=50;

This means that Oracle.ODP will keep the last 50 select statements in a cache leaving their cursor open and not parse them again.

This was very useful for my scenario. I hope it helps anyone

Comment: Yes, Statement Cache Size is the way to do this. It would be highly unusual to need more than that (suggests something wonky about your app design), but you could also have your DBA look into DBMS_SHARED_POOL.KEEP or the equivalent to pin existing cursors on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem with you database, have a look at parameter [CURSOR_SHARING](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams035.htm#REFRN10025)

When I try your code then SQL_TEXT is automatically changed to `select :"SYS_B_0" from dual /*test2*/` I also used Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.122.1.0

```
SELECT s.FETCHES,s.PARSE_CALLS,s.sql_Text,s.sql_id, executions
FROM v$SQL s 
WHERE sql_Text LIKE 'select :"SYS_B_0" from dual /*test2*/';

FETCHES PARSE_CALLS SQL_TEXT    SQL_ID  EXECUTIONS
18006   14  select :"SYS_B_0" from dual /*test2*/   bk52pdazabzff   18006
```

Comment: We're using the same oracle version. In your connection, what is the value of Statement Cache?

Comment: I have to check but I used all default in connection string